# Python and R interaction

Tags: r, python-3.x, teradata

I need to call an R script from Python, but my challenge is to call a specific R environment (32bit) is this possible?

A bit more color on my issue.  I use python 64 bit and need to connect to a 32 bit teradata dns, unfortunately I can not change the odbc drivers, thus not able to run my teradata from python 64bit.  I already have R 32 and 64 bit, and would like to be able to call my script on my R32bit.  Is this possible?

Unfortunately,I am not allowed to install Python 32bit.

I currently use Windows 7 with Python 64 and R 64 and 32bit version.

Regards,
Aksel

Comment: Are R 32 bit and R 64 bit separate software? Then you can call the `Rscript` for 32 bit version using the fullpath from Python, say via [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: If windows, then you can choose `.../R-3.5.1/bin/i386/Rscript.exe` or `.../R-3.5.1/bin/x64/Rscript.exe` for the 32- and 64-bit version, respectively. (If you want more help, it might be useful to include your OS, R, and python versions.)

Comment: Both, thank you very much. My script should should look something like subprocess.call(["/path/R-3.5.1/bin/i386/Rscript.exe", "/path/Rscript.R"]) is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the two complementing comments, the solution is to use python's subprocess to call the R script using the relevant built.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["FullPath/R3.4.3/bin/i386/Rscript.exe","FullPathe/test.R"])
```